# Joomla 3.3 - where to find html source editor and edit it

Tags: html, joomla, web

I have installed joomla 3.3 and I couldn't find the HTML source editor to embed some html code in my website.

Comment: Well it depends on which part of website you want to embed that code.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense .. do you literally mean you don't know how to create new content? (Have you logged in to the administrator and tried something like Content>Articles>New? This is not a programming question, you really just need to read the beginners guide on the Joomla documentation site.

Comment: Are you asking if you can display non rendered html? Or that you just want to paste in some html? All joomla editors come with a toggle button that puts you into a straight html screen.   If you want to edit the html that makes the layout for a page you can go to the template editor and create an override for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're referring to Joomla's text editor or editing the template HTML markup so I've added screenshots for both:

## Text editor:

[image]

---

## Template editing:

[image]

If you go into the template files, open you will see (on the left hand side) the index.php file which contains the HTML markup for the template. However I would recommend using a module rather than editing the templates core files

Comment: in the current release you can easily copy any layout to the template and override it there, so that's what i would do if that is the requirement. If you are going to actually edit the index.php I'd make a new copy of the template and work on the copy.